# Finding coordinates relative to survey base point and project base point

Tags: c#, revit-api

I've been searching alot about this subject (and read alot) but can't find a solution.
I'm trying to find the coordinates for a point relative to the project base point.
I've found how to get them relative to the survey point as following:

```
ProjectLocation pl = doc.ActiveProjectLocation;
Transform ttr = pl.GetTotalTransform().Inverse;
 ProjectPosition projPosition = doc.ActiveProjectLocation.get_ProjectPosition(new XYZ(0, 0, 0));
LocationPoint loc = element.Location as LocationPoint;
if (loc != null)
{
    XYZ point = ttr.OfPoint(loc.Point);
}
```

this works perfectly even if I change the "The angle to the true north" but I can't find a way to get the position relative to the project base point.
Has someone have a solution for this?

greets

Answer (score 0):

The base point can be retrieved through a `FilteredElementCollector` for `BasePoint` elements. Each `BasePoint` has a `Location` property that you can get to retrieve and set to move the point, cf., http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/11/survey-and-project-base-point.html.

Comment: i've done the following

    var basePoints = doc.NewFilteredElementCollector().OfClass<BasePoint();
    var projectPoint = basePoints.First(x => !x.IsShared);

and i can get the coordinates but the problem is getting the coordinates of my point relative to this base point